# How to deploy clustered Kubernetes including an application (ex. nginx) using azure arm template

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I can create kubernetes cluster on azure using arm template but can not include my application on kubernetes or any other application in the same arm template.

Any idea is that possible or any equivalent solution to delpoying kubernetes clustered containing my application on azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible without hacks, really. you could try and get enrolled into the [Azure Terraform Resource Provider Private Preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-azure-terraform-resource-provider/), but I dont think this is getting anywhere, as its been over a year with no news on this.

And the hacks would be to create an Azure Container Instance and instruct it to talk to the cluster and deploy whatever you need to deploy or doing the same using an Azure Function.

Comment: Is that hack using ACI possible using azure arm template?

Comment: yes, it is, create an ACI instance, use a container with kubectl, pass it the kubeconfig and commands to issue